# Object array implementation in reactJS store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, store

I know how to use reactJS store, but I've got a problem when I used the store with object array.

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        array: [{ id: null, summary: "", name: "" }]
      };
    }

componentWillMount() {
  const query = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=game";
  var dataCount;
  axios.get(query).then(response => {
    dataCount = response.data.length;
  });

  axios.get(query).then(response => {
    for (let i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {

      if (response.status) {
        this.setState({
          array: [
            ...this.state.array,
            {
              id: i,
              summary: response.data[i].show.summary,
              name: response.data[i].show.name
            }
          ]
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

> Actually, I did code this but there are a bunch of problems. it is
>   storing array[0] in this.state.array[0] 8-9 times. When I write
>   console.log(this.state.array[0]) it doesn't print only one instance.
>   Always prints the object about axios GET method Response Count times.
>   I want to storing objects like
>   this.state.array[0]={id:1, summary:"xyz",name:"abc"}, this.state.array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqvW6.jpg)={id:1, summary:"xyz", name:"abc"}.

[image: image here]

Comment: Why are you sending two axios requests?

Comment: one is getting a count of data, the other one is getting data with using for loop. but you are right one is enough

Comment: You don't have to do this with two requests. Both of them are running asynchronously, so there's no guarantee that at the time when second one being resolved, value of `dataCount` is not still `undefined`. Just put them together.

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no need to send two requests here. You can get the data and the data length and work with it all in one single request. It'll actually be better that way, because the axios requests won't be resolved in order, so you might not always have the length by the time the code loops.
2. Could probably go with a better name for the array in state, like `shows`
3. There's an initial empty item in there for seemingly no reason, can probably toss that.
4. It would probably be more straight-forward to store the fetched data into state directly instead of pulling specific keys from it like this, but this one's minor.
5. Use `componentDidMount`. [`componentWillMount` is deprecated.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html)

[See this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/48wz43pzm4)

Comment: yeah but I want to write functions to use properties of an object as a function parameter to apply functions like string parsing and get that words from passage and use them in another place. In this way, I am very addicted to that response data mapping. It does not quite fit react's store logic. this.state.shows is empty.